# How to add a filter search bar in JS

Tags: javascript, html, function

```js
const sounds = [
  'Jason',
  'lil Jon',
  'mario',
  'TwoClock',
  'beep boppy',
  'Dixon Cider',
  'Baldy',
  'PK Fire',
  'look Eye',
  'Show up'
];

sounds.forEach((sound) => {
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.classList.add('btn'); // sound button formula
  btn.innerText = sound;
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // stopSongs();
    document.getElementById(sound).play();
  });

  document.getElementById('buttons').appendChild(btn);
});

//#19 stops sound from playing when you click on another button


//adding a filter for our search
```

```html
<h1>Dr s</h1>
<h2>Sound board</h2>

<!--Filter-->
```

I tried looking up and could not find a way to add a filter search for buttons. I know it should be a function just struggling on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

This might be your solution, you forgot to add `})` to the end of one of your functions. Your code should work now!

```js
const sounds=[
'Jason',
'lil Jon',
'mario',
'TwoClock',
'beep boppy',
'Dixon Cider',
'Baldy',
'PK Fire',
'look Eye',
'Show up'
];

sounds.forEach((sound) => {
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.classList.add('btn');
  btn.innerText = sound;

  btn.addEventListener('click', () =>{

    document.getElementById('buttons').appendChild(btn); 
    }); // <= You forgot this
});
```

```html
<div id="buttons">

</div>
```